# Difference between presentModalViewController and presentViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

In iOS 5 SDK, there're two methods of UIViewController, presentModalViewController:animated: and presentViewController:animated:completion:.

What's the difference between these two method?

The documentation says: The presentViewController:animated:completion: method is the preferred way to present a modal view as of iOS 5.0.

If I use a presentModalViewController:animated in iOS 5, will it causes a bug?

Are they functionally-same?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

They seem to do the same thing as apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) points out, as of iOS 5.0 `presentViewController` is the preferred way to present view controllers, it seems that `presentViewController` now lets you have a completion handler, whereas before you did not have that.

And no the older `presentModalViewController` should be fine on iOS 5.0, if it caused a bug that would be a problem for all the older apps and would not be very backward compatible. Furthermore it seems that now with `presentViewController` you can get a lot more info about the viewController hierarchy as we have `presentingViewController`, `presentedViewController` properties.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that if I target iOS 5, I should always use presentViewController.

Comment: Yea if you have an iOS 5 only app yes

Answer (score 13):

Another important note is that presentModalViewController will be deprecated in the future, as mentioned in the UIViewController.h of the UIKit framework (Xcode version 4.3.1):

```
// Display another view controller as a modal child. Uses a vertical sheet transition if animated.This method has been replaced by presentViewController:animated:completion:
// It will be DEPRECATED, plan accordingly.
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated; 

// Dismiss the current modal child. Uses a vertical sheet transition if animated. This method has been replaced by dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:
// It will be DEPRECATED, plan accordingly.
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated;
```