# UIAlertView cancel button crashes app

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, uialertview, nszombie

Okay, so I have just started iOS development. I'll start by explaining the flow of my app : 

1. A view called "appViewController" is loaded.

2. `[self presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion:nil];` this loads a webview

3. After I am done with the webview, I dismiss it and load a new UINavigation this way :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        formViewController *fv = [ [formViewController alloc] init ];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fv] autorelease];
        navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
        [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    }];
```

5.The formViewController has a button, which has the event attached to it for that display an alert this way

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                           message:@"test"
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];
```

Everything works as intended up till here. Now when I click the "Ok"(Cancel) button, the app crashes with NSZombieEnabled saying
**-[appViewController _deepestDefaultFirstResponder]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6e6a570 lldb**

What is happening here? Why is it trying to send message to appViewController again? There is no code after [av show]

NOTE : I am using ARC

Comment: Do you have the didSelectButtonAtIndex delegate method in your view controller?

Comment: You're not using ARC if you've got calls to `autorelease`.

Comment: @warrenm Using ARC on the controller that triggers the alert. The other file which is actually loading the view (the one you see autorelease on) has been flagged with -fno-objc-arc

Comment: @Jeremy1026 No I don't, but since I only have a "Cancel" button and delegate:nil, do I really need that?

Comment: @AyushChaudhary No you don't need it. Was just a question to see if maybe something in that method was wonky. Since its not there, it is ruled out as the cause.

Comment: What else do you suspect? I have gone through most of the similar question but none of the solutions have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using arc, the autorelease in your code isn't valid.

This seems like your root view controller gets deallocated at some point and when the responder chain gets traversed the resulting dangling pointer gets accessed.

To verify this, I would implement the dealloc method on appViewController and see if it gets called.

```
dealloc {
  NSLog(@"Problems ahead.");
}
```

If this does get called before you'd expect that to happen (for a root view controller probably not at all), you need to find out why this happens. You're probably missing a strong reference somewhere. Check you app delegate and verify that you have a strong reference to the window and that you are setting your controller as the root view controller (provided you're not using storyboards).

The Zombies instrument is very good for debugging such problems. It will list all retains and releases of your problematic object. [Here's a short introduction to it](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/).

Comment: Okay, firstly, autorelease is only there in files which have been flagged as -fno-objc-arc. Yes, the rootviewcontroller (appViewController) does get deallocated, but why do I need it at all? why is it being called at all? and how do I avoid that? I am using storyboards

Comment: It has to stay around since it's the base for the other view controllers you are adding (appViewController->webViewCotnroller at first and appViewController->presentingViewController after that).

Comment: The appViewController is getting deallocated when [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion .... is being called, the app still pushes the fv controller, in the IBAction that currently triggers the alert, if I just do NSLog, it works fine, only crashes when I press the cancel button on the alert. Any clue?

Comment: Is presentingViewController pointing to the appViewController? If so, you are adding a new modal view controller (navController) on top of it. When we add a modal view controller onto a view controller, we can't let the presenting view controller go away. It probably crashes when you press the button because a new event comes in and the responder chain gets traversed (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Responder.html). This also accesses appController and causes a crash inside _deepestDefaultFirstResponder.

Comment: You're right. Before I called [self dismissViewController... I had this UIViewController *presentingViewController = [self.presentingViewController autorelease]; which probably shouldn't have been there (cause I didn't own it? Is that right?) Changing it to UIViewController *presentingViewController = self.presentingViewController; solved it but, I don't know why. Is it because the autorelease was causing a memory leak and explicitly causing the rootViewcontroller to be deallocated? Could you please explain the mistake?

Comment: Yes, autoreleasing the object returned from self.presentingViewController would be incorrect. This is a standard accessor (getter), an it does not transfer ownership of the object, so you are not responsible for releasing it, unless you retain it first. I suggest that you take a look at the [memory management programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) for details.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15659/discussion-between-ayush-chaudhary-and-matej-bukovinski)

Comment: @AyushChaudhary Matej is right you haven't taken the owenership of the  presentingViewController you should retain it before it is deallocated. When you present a controller it is retained and when you dismiss it, it is released.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.

1. You are mixing presentViewController and presentModalViewController.  If you are new to iOS, you should always use presentViewController.  No need getting used to using a method that will soon be deprecated (see answer to this question [Difference between presentModalViewController and presentViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365263/difference-between-presentmodalviewcontroller-and-presentviewcontroller)
2. In general, you shouldn't autorelease unless you absolutely have to.  Since when a controller is presented with presentViewController (and presentModalViewController), it is retained, you can readily release afterwards.  I would restructure like so:

> ```
> UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fv];
> navController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
> [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
> [navController release];
> ```

3.. Where is the section of code you included located?  Like, you push a button and the view is dismissed or what?

Comment: Re 1: Could that be relevant to this issue? Re 2 : I'll try without the autorelease and update you here Re 3 : in fv.xib I have a button which when pressed, trigger an IBAction which triggers the alert